# Clean way to automate terminal commands in multiple windows and return to prompt in each?

Tags: macos, bash

So, as part of my workflow right now, anytime I pull up a project I open two terminal windows alongside it - one to manipulate and monitor `git`, and one to manipulate and monitor `gulp/grunt`. As it stands, I open these windows manually, navigate to the appropriate roots, and run the initial commands - its growing very tedious and time-consuming.

I've been looking for a way to automate this process and remove some of the manual steps from it, and I've made some progress - I've written a `.command` file that, when-double-clicked, opens two new terminal windows and executes scripts I've specified.

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")/_launchscripts/"
open -a Terminal.app ./git.command
open -a Terminal.app ./grunt.command
```

File structure for clarity:

```
_launch.command
_launchscripts/
    git.command
    grunt.command
```

In order to get around the terminal window exiting immediately upon completion, I learned you can simply open a new login shell session with `bash -l`. So, my `git.command` and `grunt.command` look like this:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")/../build/path/to/root"
[git or grunt status commands]
bash -l
```

The problem now is that each terminal window has two bash sessions open, one nested in the other. This is a bit of an annoyance, as the terminal window now prompts "Are you sure you want to close this window running bash(2)?" on close instead of closing immediately - but more importantly, I feel any further efforts I make to dig deeper will just make this overcomplicated. I want to bring this back to simplicity and elegance.

There has to be an easier way to go about this. Is it possible, on double-click, to spawn more than one shell window, run a couple of simple commands in each, and return to the original shell prompt - or at least open a new shell and kill the parent? I'm open to any clever alternatives as well, I'm certain there are other approaches I'm not knowledgeable enough to consider.